# Name dataframe and .csv output by first column header/variable

Tags: r, excel, csv, variables

new to R and programming generally, read a few other posts that seem similar to this, but I can't be sure.  Here's what I'm trying to do - import data from Excel, name the dataframe after the variable/column header in the first column in Excel, perform statistical tests in R, and then write a .csv output with the filename being the same as the first variable/column header in the original Excel (also now the same name as the dataframe).

I have several hundred regressions I need to estimate via a loop, and need the saved .csv outputs to have unique filenames so that I can tell them apart, so I have a dummy variable with that name as the first column in the Excel input.

This is the way that seems easiest for my abilities to do this, so I'd appreciate any insight!  Also, if others can suggest easier ways, in addition, that would of course be most helpful.  Thank you!

Comment: All, I'm following up on this comment.  I've figured some things out myself, I am now using the following code to at least isolate the dummy variable that I want to use as the file naming variable.  

x<-dataframe[,1]
names(x)

This provides the title that I want, not sure how to get it into the file name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing much about your folder/file structure or the tests you plan to perform, then this basic for loop may work as a skeleton for what you are attempting to accomplish.

```
library(readxl)

# Create a vector storing files to be read
files <- c("file1.xlsx","file2.xlsx","file3.xlsx")

# Loop through each file
for(i in 1:length(files)){
  # Read file into dataframe
  df <- read_excel(files[i])

  # Set the output filepath to be the same as the first column header
  out.file <- colnames(df)[1]


  # Perform tests on dataframe here


  # Write the processed dataframe to the output filepath
  write.csv(df, out.file, row.names = FALSE)
}
```